# PWA Active field

Tags: project-server, pwa

When I look at the project level fields in PWA there is one called Active.  What is the use of that?  Is that supposed to be is the project active.   We do have projects that are ideas, but no one is working on them.  Is that what it should be used for?   How would I edit that field?  When I add it to a Project Detail Page, I cannot edit it?

Comment: task field or project field? Can you add an image?

Comment: It is a Project field.  Here you can see it when I am creating a Project detail page.  ![Example](http://i.imgur.com/hnUU4KW.png)

Comment: Are you sure it is not a custom field?

Comment: I don't see it under the Enterprise Custom Fields

Comment: I cannot find this field in documentation.